# Etcdctl get a lot of garbage info after upgrade aip-server to use etcdv3 api

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I'm upgrading etcd to v3.0.17 for k8s to use etcdv3 api.

After etcd upgraded and apiserver started without 'storage-backend=etcd2' and 'storage-media-type=application/json' defined, I noticed that etcdctl get can't display some info properly, like this:

```
/_egi_+_y/c-+fig+a-_/++be-_y_+e+/fi+ebea+-_-a_+-c-+f
{"+i+d":"C-+figMa-","a-iVe__i-+":"+1","+e+ada+a":{"+a+e":"fi+ebea+-_-a_+-    c-+f","+a+e_-ace":"++be-_y_+e+","+id":"9a09cef0-348c-11e7-ba37- 1418775d636e","c_ea+i-+Ti+e_+a+-":"2017-05-09T07:53:34Z"},"da+a":{"fi+ebea+.y++":"fi+ebea+:\+  -_-_-ec+-__:\+  -\+    i+-++_+y-e: +-g\+    d-c++e++_+y-e: _-a_+\+    fie+d_:\+      +a+e_-ace: ++be-_y_+e+\+    fie+d__++de___--+: +_+e\+    -a+h_:\+      - /+-g/*/*/_+de__\+  -\+    i+-++_+y-e: +-g\+    d-c++e++_+y-e: _-a_+\+    fie+d_:\+      +a+e_-ace: ++be-_y_+e+\+    fie+d__++de___--+: +_+e\+    -a+h_:\+      - /+-g/*/*/_+d-++\+\+-++-++:\+  +-g_+a_h:\+    h-_+_: [\"192.168.197.200:5044\",\"192.168.197.199:5044\"]\+    +-_+e_: 4\+    c-+-_e__i-+_+e+e+: 3\+    +-adba+a+ce: +_+e\+    i+de|: ++be-_y_+e+\+"}}
```

Also, I created a new pod, it was stored in the etcd like this:

```
# ETCDCTL_API=3 /opt/bin/etcdctl --endpoints http://10.3.7.27:2379 get /registry/pods/default/busybox-116p6
/registry/pods/default/busybox-116p6
k8s

v1Pod¯

ã
busybox-116pbusybox-default"-/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/busybox-116p6*$1cc8a15c-5996-11e8-ac41-1418775d2f8528B
                                                                                                              ý¯ô×‹Ä‰îZ
a--b+_yb-|Z&
c-++_-++e_-_e+i_i-+-ha_h
1615036418Z
--d-+e+-+a+e-ge+e_a+i-+1bû
++be_+e+e_.i-/c_ea+ed-byÞ{"+i+d":"Se_ia+izedRefe_e+ce","a-iVe__i-+":"+1","_efe_e+ce":{"+i+d":"Dae+-+Se+","+a+e_-ace":"defa+++","+a+e":"b+_yb-|","+id":"fa90b377-44a0-11e8-83ca-1418775d636e","a-iVe__i-+":"e|+e+_i-+_","_e_-+_ceVe__i-+":"100605842"}}
b.
*_ched++e_.a+-ha.++be_+e+e_.i-/c_i+ica+---d+R
    Dae+-+Se+b+_yb-|"$fa90b377-44a0-11e8-83ca-1418775d636e*e|+e+_i-+_/+1be+a108zý
1
defa+++-+-+e+-+8g9+2
defa+++-+-+e+-+8g9+¤è
b+_yb-|-_egi_+_y.-_-d.+ca_i+c.c-+/+--+_/b+_yb-|:g+ibc/bi+/_h-c+hi+e +_+e; d- _+ee- 3600; d-+e*BJH
defa+++-+-+e+-+8g9+-/+a_/_++/_ec_e+_/++be_+e+e_.i-/_e_+iceacc-+++"+/de+/+e_+i+a+i-+-+-g_
                                                                                        IfN-+P_e_e++€ˆ¢Fi+eA++ay_ 2
                                                                                                                C++_+e_Fi__+Bdefa+++Jdefa+++Raz06.++_.+ab.+ca_i+c.c-+X`h_‚Ššdefa+++-_ched++e_²8
!+-de.a+-ha.++be_+e+e_.i-/+-+ReadyE|i_+_"       N-E|ec++e²;
$+-de.a+-ha.++be_+e+e_.i-/++_eachab+eE|i_+_"    N-E|ec++eÆ
R+++i+g#

I+i+ia+izedT_+ý¯ô×*2
ReadyT_+þ¯ô×*2$

P-dSched++edT_+þ¯ô×*2"* 10.3.7.342172.29.224.22ý¯ô×B›
b+_yb-|


þ¯ô× (2-_egi_+_y.-_-d.+ca_i+c.c-+/+--+_/b+_yb-|:g+ibc:d-c+e_--+++ab+e://_egi_+_y.-_-d.+ca_i+c.c-+/+--+_/b+_yb-|@_ha256:9f5597958a437eacae2634ff71b9f28f94720a3bf43378c1db282693c4fed9e5BId-c+e_://4c54e2b9224f0b2545311f272b08af110a557941efa7d77f9207f8ec617be37dJ
Be_+Eff-_+"
```

What's wrong with here? The data write through v3 api by apiserver is not readable?

My environment: Coreos 1298.5.0, kubernetes v1.7.10, etcd v3.0.17

Answer (score 0):

It should be readable with the `storage-media-type=application/json` flag.

The output of your command looks like JSON, but with something like broken encoding.

Try to dump the output to a file, not to a terminal and read it by some other tool or on the other server.

Comment: I has outputed to a file and edit with vi, and transfered to my pc , opened it with word, using utf-8 encoding, no luck. or what's your suggestion about the edit tools?

Comment: Yes, that was my suggestion. Is your cluster work well? The problem only with reading from etcd? Maybe it is an issue with `etcdctl`? BTW, try to update your cluster at least to 1.8.X, 1.7.X is already obsolete.

Comment: Yes, it's only with reading from etcd. After migrating the data from v2 to v3, before start apiserver, I read all key-values from etcd, all is fine, no garbages. Then I start apiserver, problem appears.  Also, k8s seems running ok, delete pod, create pod, but I don't know if there are other hidden trouble. I doubt  It's a bug or something, but it's weird that nobody ever reported it.

Comment: Upgraded kubernetes to 1.8.12, with etcd v3.0.17, same result, any point ?

Comment: this is working as designed. more info refter to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44670

Comment: @KunLi yes, but "if you want to integrate JSON-reading tools directly against etcd, that is not recommended, but you can continue to do that by making k8s continue to store JSON in etcd with --storage-media-type=application/json". And you told that you set that flag. That's why I am confused a bit about that problem...

Comment: Thank you, Kostenko. I ignored 'json' totally in your first answer, maybe it's something called blind area.